# translate javascript to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to translate this javascript code to jquery i try several time but it very hard, please apologize my english cause i'm french and its not easy for me ^^
thank so much.

```
(function () {
    var more = document.getElementById('more');
    more.addEventListener('click', function (evenement) {
        evenement.preventDefault();

        var cible = document.getElementById('question');
        if (cible.style.display == 'none') {
            cible.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            cible.style.display = 'none';
        }
        return false;
    });

    var form = document.getElementById('formulaire');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (evenement) {
        evenement.preventDefault();
        /* Récupération des informations */
        var image = form.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
        var espece = document.getElementById('espece');
        var poil = document.getElementById('poil');
        var _certain = document.getElementsByName('certain');
        var certain = null;

        for (var i = 0; i < _certain.length; i++) {
            if (_certain[i].checked) {
                certain = _certain[i];
            }
        }

        var continent = form.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
        var continent_valeur = continent.options[continent.selectedIndex].value;

        /* Test des champs */
        if (espece.value == '' || poil.value == '' || certain.value == '' || continent_valeur == "") {
            alert("Veuillez remplir tous les champs !");
            return false;
        }

        /* On remplit les élements des valeurs renseignées */
        var resultat = document.getElementById('resultat');
        var _paragraphes = resultat.getElementsByTagName('p');
        var valeur_image = image.getAttribute('src');
        var image_resultat = resultat.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
        image_resultat.setAttribute('src', valeur_image);
        var valeur_espece_poil = '... je suis donc un(e) ' + espece.value + ' à poils ' + poil.value;
        var paragraphepremier = _paragraphes[0];
        paragraphepremier.innerHTML = valeur_espece_poil;
        var valeur_continent = '<span class="big">... et mon continent d\'origine est : "' + continent_valeur + '"</span>';
        var dernierparagraphe = _paragraphes[_paragraphes.length - 1];
        dernierparagraphe.innerHTML = valeur_continent;
        /* On affiche le bloc de résultat */
        form.style.display = "none";
        resultat.style.display = "block";
        return false;
    }, false);
})();
```

i hope you can help me.
i try to watch many example in internet too but i have the same result.

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/) has all you need. [Selecting Elements](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/), [Manipulating Elements](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/), [Events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/)

Comment: thank for editing et for your advice

Comment: Tu n'a qu'a trouver les fonctions equivalentes JQuery de chaque fonction pure JS. Par exemple, document.getElementById('more') est remplaçable par $("#more"), getElementByTagName('img') par form.find("img"), etc.

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda j ai exactement fait ça mais ensuite je bloque au niveau del'utilisation des variable par exemple pour appliquer un evenement a une variable j'ai du mal  var form = document.getElementById('formulaire'); var form = $('#formulaire');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(evenement){ 
evenement.preventDefault();
$('form').blind('submit', function(evenement){ 
evenement.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

Pour repondre a ton commentaire, avec JQuery on peut utiliser `submit()` sur un element, a la place de `addEventListener`:

```
var form = $('#formulaire'); 
form.submit(function( evenement ) {
    alert("Submitted!");
    evenement.preventDefault(); 
}
```

Ca prends juste un peu de recherche et du Google-fu.